# How do I read a certain date range from a partitioned parquet file in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a large parquet file that is written to daily and partitioned by snapshot date (in long form). I am trying to write an app that takes a date and a lookback value as input, and returns a slice of the parquet from the snapshot day to x days back.

I found a similar question that had an answer suggesting I use

```
spark.read.parquet("gs://parquet-storage-bucket/parquet-name/snapshot_date=[1564704000-1567123200]")
```

However Spark seems to take this literally and cannot find a parquet with this exact name (obviously).

Is there a way I can provide a start and end date (in long format) and have all partitions data within this range retrieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try filtering the Dataset using `filter` function:

```
spark.read.parquet("gs://parquet-storage-bucket/parquet-name")
.filter(col("snapshot_date") >= 1564704000 && col("snapshot_date") <= 1567123200)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: This solution will read entire data into data frame then perform filter operation. Is there a way we will load only required partitons

Comment: If your filter column is a partitioned column, then all data will NOT be read.